# Not able to create table using Markdown for API documentation

Tags: markdown, postman

I am Creating an API document using POSTMAN. I am trying to insert a table. but i am not able to do that. It is normally printing as text.
Anyone can tell me, How can that be done using Markdown.

I am using this as reference to create : [markdown](http://markdownlivepreview.com/)

I am trying to insert table using this : [for table](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet)

Comment: Are you trying to add the table to the Postman documentation for your API collections? The question is slightly confusing.

Comment: Tables are a non-standard Markdown feature. Not all Markdown implementations support them and not all that do, do so by default. You may need to "enable" support or use a different implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with http://markdownlivepreview.com/

If you use this site, everything is okay: https://dillinger.io/
Here the table code is working from your cheat sheet

```
| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    $1 |
```

Comment: Thank you for Replying. it is working on the site which you mentioned.